# VBA: input click getElementbyId of the next similar id

Tags: vba, automation, getelementbyid

I'm facing a issue regarding my VBA script.
My problem is, how to click on a button of an input button that has the same ID than the previous one. The only thing which differs from the other is the onclick value...
My script works for the first ADD button, but when page load I don't know how to make my code click on the new ADD button (which has the same id than the previous one). see my code below :

First load of HTML page :

```
<input id="btnEdit" class="button" onclick="openExpenseForm(1,'ExpenseCard.aspx?ExpenseFormID=c78f4ac6-63fc-4a47-a06a-a4eafe3ded08&ExpenseCardID=&Row=1&Action=New&Enabled=True');"
                        type="button" value="ADD" />
```

Second load of HTML page :

```
<input id="btnEdit" class="button" onclick="openExpenseForm(1,'ExpenseCard.aspx?ExpenseFormID=c78f4ac6-63fc-4a47-a06a-a4eafe3ded08&ExpenseCardID=&Row=1&Action=New&Enabled=True');"
                        type="button" value="EDIT" />
<input id="btnEdit" class="button" onclick="openExpenseForm(2,'ExpenseCard.aspx?ExpenseFormID=c78f4ac6-63fc-4a47-a06a-a4eafe3ded08&ExpenseCardID=&Row=1&Action=New&Enabled=True');"
                        type="button" value="ADD" />
```

VBA :

```
    Dim oIE As Object
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.Visible = True
    URL = "http://netsteps/expense/ExpenseForm.aspx?Action=New&EmployeeID=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3)
    oIE.Navigate (URL)

AppActivate oIE

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument ' html object lib
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With objIE
With ActiveSheet

    Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While oIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    oIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_Main_txtExpenseBusinessPurpose").Value = CStr(.Cells(2, 3))

    Do While (Not IsEmpty(.Cells(lin, 1)))

    Set htmlDoc = oIE.document
    Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If (htmlInput.Value = Trim("ADD") And Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "button") Then
                htmlInput.Click
            End If
        Next htmlInput

        Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While oIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        ' Process 
        'End of all loops...
```

I'm kind of stuck, any help would be gratefull.
Have a good day,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes in html documents are supposed to be unique but you assign the same value `btnEdit` in two elements. dismabiguate them, eg. by appending the content of the button's value attribute ( `btnEdit_ADD`, `btnEdit_EDIT` ). in case you need to express that the buttons are one of a kind, use a `data-`-attribute (for details, see [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) ). hope that helps, regards